# Check if a user already exists (Node.js and mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to check if a user in the database also exists. My code works if I add a user to the db without checking if someone with it's name exists. The problem appears when I try to check it, because the code can recognize if a user exists or not, but the user cannot be added to the database if this doesn't exist. The code which works is this one (the function DB() is where the code creates the connection with the database):

```
app.post('/Registro', function(req, res){
var conDB=DB();
var reg={
    Usuario: req.body.Usuario,
    Contra: req.body.Contra
};
console.log(req.body.Usuario+" "+req.body.Contra);
var query=conDB.query('INSERT INTO Usuario SET ?',reg,function(err, res){

});
res.send("Usuario: "+req.body.Usuario+" y Contraseña: "+req.body.Contra + "REGISTRADOS");
conDB.end(); });
```

The code which doesn't work (where I'm trying to check if the user exists) is this one:

```
app.post('/Registro', function(req, res){
var conDB=DB();
var reg={
    Usuario: req.body.Usuario,
    Contra: req.body.Contra
};
var UsuarioReg=req.body.Usuario;
conDB.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = ?', UsuarioReg,function(err,rows){
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    if (!rows.length)
    {
            conDB.query('INSERT INTO Usuario SET ?',reg,function(err, respuesta){
            return respuesta.send("Usuario: "+req.body.Usuario+" y Contraseña: "+
                    req.body.Contra + "REGISTRADOS");
            }); 
    }
    else
    {
        return res.send("Este usuario ya existe");
    }
});
    conDB.end(); 
});
```

If someone knows how can I solve this situation, I'd be grateful!

I have made an edition which threw this exception:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I bet the database connection is closing before the queries get executed. I'd move `conDB.end()` into the `err` handler from the first query and into the callback function of the second query.

EDIT:

```
app.post('/Registro', function(req, res){
    var conDB=DB();
    var reg={
        Usuario: req.body.Usuario,
        Contra: req.body.Contra
    };
    var UsuarioReg=req.body.Usuario;
    var ContraReg=req.body.Contra;
    conDB.query('SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario = ? and Contra= ?',  [UsuarioReg,ContraReg]
,function(err,rows){
    if(err) {
        conDB.end();
        return console.log(err);
    }

    if (!rows.length)
    {
        conDB.query('INSERT INTO Usuario SET ?',reg,function(err, results){
            conDB.end();
            return res.send("Usuario: "+req.body.Usuario+" y Contraseña: "+
                req.body.Contra + "REGISTRADOS");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        conDB.end();
        return res.send("Este usuario ya existe");
    }
});

});
```

Comment: I have changed the code but it still doesn't work. What I did was taking out the part that says  return res.send("Usuario: "+req.body.Usuario+" y Contraseña: "+req.body.Contra + "REGISTRADOS"); from the function that adds the user to the database. There must be a problem with that function. Cannot I ask two times to the database without closing the connection in Node.js??

Comment: You definitely can. Are you seeing an error from the first query in the console? Or are you getting the `user already exists` response?

Comment: When the user already exists, it throws me a message that says it exists. But now, having the return down the function like the first situation which is working well, it doesn't throw an error. It only says that the new user was registered but, when I open the database, it doesn't appear

Comment: Another problem I just saw: after you attempt to insert in your callback function you have `res` as the second parameter. You are trying to send an http response with `res`, but you are overriding that variable so `res` isn't the HTTP response at this point

Comment: What variable are you saying that I'm overheading? The once that you can see when I use the function res.send in the places like req.body.Usuario and req.body.Contra?

Comment: ahhh. I think I'm understanding what you're saying. I did this now: 
conDB.query('INSERT INTO Usuario SET ?',reg,function(err, respuesta){ }); 
return res.send("Usuario: "+req.body.Usuario+" y Contraseña: "+ req.body.Contra + "REGISTRADOS");

Comment: But apart from that, the main problem is that the conDB.query is not adding the user to the db...that's I cannot understand. It enters to the function without any problem but when it gets inside the function of insert it doesn't work :(

Comment: how can I edit it?? I FINALLY MADE SOMETHING THAT THREW AN ERROR!!!! :) But I don't know where's the option to edit it...

Comment: Under the tags on your original post there should be an `edit` button. Right below where you say `If someone knows how can I solve this situation, I'd be grateful!

`

Comment: I have edited it with the code which throws me the error. I hope this can help you

Comment: I updated my answer. It looks an error occurred since `respuesta` was undefined. It looks like you were still calling `conDB.end()` before the second query had a chance to finish. This has to do with database queries being asynchronous. See my updated answer and make sure you are only calling `conDB.end()` in those same places

Comment: I have updated the code with your changes. Now I have another error message which comes from the client (you can read it on the image because I changed it for the client's error)

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! I HAD A MISTAKE WHEN I WAS PASSING YOUR CODE. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I HAVE A NEW IDOL ?)

Answer (score 2):

Thank for your idea. It is help for me. Then I can make route for sign up in my code.

```
            var express = require("express");
            var router = express.Router();
            //var usersModel = require("../models/users");
            var db = require("../common/database");
            var conn = db.getConnection();
            router.get("/", function (req, res) {
                res.json({ "message": "This is Admin page" });
            })
            router.get("/register_success/:email", function (req, res) {
                res.render("register_success", { email: req.params.email });
            })
            router.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
                res.render("signup", {
                    data: {
                        email: "",
                        password: "",
                        first_name: "",
                        last_name: ""
                    }, error: false, message: ""
                });
            })
            router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
                var user = req.body;
                var Oneuser = {
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.passwd,
                    first_name: user.firstname,
                    last_name: user.lastname,
                    created_at: new Date()
                };
                conn.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [Oneuser.email]
                    , function (err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            conn.end();
                            console.log(err);
                            res.render("signup", {
                                data: {
                                    email: user.email,
                                    password: user.passwd,
                                    first_name: user.firstname,
                                    last_name: user.lastname
                                }, error: true, message: err
                            });
                        }
                        if (!rows.length) {
                            conn.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', Oneuser, function (err2, results) {
                                if (err2) {
                                    console.log(err2);
                                    res.render("signup", {
                                        data: {
                                            email: user.email,
                                            password: user.passwd,
                                            first_name: user.firstname,
                                            last_name: user.lastname
                                        }, error: true, message: err2
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    res.redirect("/admin/register_success/" + Oneuser.email);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Email is exists");
                            res.render("signup", {
                                data: {
                                    email: user.email,
                                    password: user.passwd,
                                    first_name: user.firstname,
                                    last_name: user.lastname
                                }, error: true, message: "Email is exists"
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
            module.exports = router;
```